# Getting "undefined symbol" on Imutils import on Python WEB Page

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, lampp, imutils

Im running Python Web pages with Apache/Lampp in Ubuntu 18.04, and I have a code that's already running ok in terminal, but when I run on browser with Apache I get this error:

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol FT_Get_Var_Blend_Coordinates

This error occurs when i try to import the "non_max_supression" from imutils.

With just this lines of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
print("Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8\n")
import sys

try:
   from imutils.object_detection import non_max_supression
except Exception as exc
   print(exc)
```

I've read in a lot of places that this can be a problem with FreeType library, so I've tried to uninstall, then tested and then installed again, tested again, but nothing changes. Some places says that it's a problem with infinality bundle, but I haven't installed that.